# Combine results of SQL query that comes from a sub-query

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have the following query for Oracle SQL, that I run with Java in my API:

```sql
"SELECT NID, MIN(START_DATE) AS START_DATE_, MAX(END_DATE) AS END_DATE_, HID, TYPE, URL FROM (" +
                    "SELECT NID, DATESTART AS START_DATE, DATEEND AS END_DATE, RID AS HID, 'HISTORICAL' AS TYPE,URL " +
                    "FROM HISTORICAL " +
                    "WHERE READER = :userId AND DISPLAY = 1 " +
                    "UNION " +
                    "SELECT NID, DATE AS START_DATE, DATE AS END_DATE, null as HID, 'VISUALIZATION' AS TYPE , null " +
                    "FROM VISUALIZATIONS " +
                    "WHERE READER = :userId AND SHOW = 1 " +
                    "UNION " +
                    "SELECT NID, DATE AS START_DATE, DATE AS END_DATE, null as HID, 'OTHER' AS TYPE, null " +
                    "FROM OTHER " +
                    "WHERE READER = :userId AND SHOW = 1 AND TYPEREMOTE != 'OR' " +
                    ") GROUP BY NID, TYPE, HID, URL " +
                    "ORDER BY MAX(END_DATE) DESC " +
                    "OFFSET :offset ROWS FETCH NEXT :size ROWS ONLY";
```

The problems that I have, is that his query will sometimes give me 'duplicates', based on the `NID` value, and doing `distinct` won't work, and also it't not accurate.

What I want is to combine, in these cases that I have more than one row sharing the same `NID`, the `START_DATE_` values and the `END_DATE_`. More accurately, in the `START_DATE_` value, I want to store the earliest possible value of that column (i.e: between '2021-04-30' and '2021-05-01', I want the first one), and the opposite for `END_DATE_`.

Actual results:

```sql
NID, START_DATE, END_DATE_, HID
5, 2021-04-30, 2021-05-10, 60
5, 2021-04-23, 2021-05-09, 70
5, 2021-01-01, 2021-02-01, 80
```

What I want:

```sql
NID, START_DATE, END_DATE_, HID
5, 2021-01-01, 2021-05-10, idc
```

I have tried using some `min` and `max` functions, and also a subquery, but I can't make it work so far.

Answer (score 0):

> The problems that I have, is that his query will sometimes give me 'duplicates', based on the NID value, and doing distinct won't work, and also it't not accurate.

You `GROUP BY NID, TYPE, HID, URL` which will give you values for each combination of `NID` and `TYPE` and `HID` and `URL`.

If you want to group all the `NID` values together then only `GROUP BY` that one thing.

```sql
SELECT NID,
       MIN(START_DATE) AS START_DATE_,
       MAX(END_DATE) AS END_DATE_
FROM   (
  SELECT NID, DATESTART AS START_DATE, DATEEND AS END_DATE
  FROM   HISTORICAL
  WHERE  READER = :userId AND DISPLAY = 1
UNION
  SELECT NID, DATE AS START_DATE, DATE AS END_DATE
  FROM   VISUALIZATIONS
  WHERE  READER = :userId AND SHOW = 1
UNION
  SELECT NID, DATE AS START_DATE, DATE AS END_DATE
  FROM   OTHER
  WHERE READER = :userId AND SHOW = 1 AND TYPEREMOTE != 'OR'
)
GROUP BY NID
ORDER BY MAX(END_DATE) DESC
OFFSET :offset ROWS FETCH NEXT :size ROWS ONLY
```

If you want to include `HID`, `TYPE` and `URL` then wrap them in aggregation functions.